# I need help on how to redirect the user back to insert a title if they try to create a book without a title and create a book if they did put a title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /books
  # GET /books.json
  def index
      @books = Book.all
  end

  # GET /books/1
  # GET /books/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /books/new
  def new
      @book = Book.new
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /books
  # POST /books.json
  def create

    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book_params = ''
      redirect_to new_book_path
    else
      respond_to do |format|
         if @book.save
           format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
         else
           format.html { render :new }
           format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
       end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /books/1
  # PATCH/PUT /books/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /books/1
  # DELETE /books/1.json
  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :read)
    end
end
```

Comment: Hello, please reformat the post and formulate a valid question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: guessing on the title -> you need to add title validation inside Book model -> and your controller action create already renders :new partial when book.save fails (due to validation)